# want to live monitor all log files in one vieuw

Tags: tail, syslog, monit, multitail

I like to view all log files live

like `tail -n0 somelog.log`
But then for literally all log files on the system (CentOS 7)

Or an other way to do this is also nice.
I want to output this to a web page eventually.

Comment: You can use splunk with real-time search